# Pass my action to other line

Tags: android

I want to pass my action to other line how can i use it? Is there any function in android which move the compiler into any action?

Here is my Code:

```
if (symbol == null) {
    symbol = "mod";
    String tv = text1.getText().toString();
    num1 = Double.valueOf(tv);
    text1.setText("");
}
else {
    //I need any there which move it on switch case.                   
}
```

Comment: Sorry but the question is unclear, can you re-phrase a bit? thanks.

Comment: This question is not understandable, what you want to say so be clear and specific.

Comment: Can't understand what you are asking

Comment: I want to move my action to a specific line like when we use goto in C++ or return Action in C#.